# Which is best data storage type to store data received from server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, data-persistence

I have certain data that is received from the server, I call it History. Everytime I visit some website, I have to save the URL in the History list.
The list will be displayed in a table later on, for the user to view.
What data storage type should I use on iPhone? Can this list be stored in `NSUserDefaults` or I have to use CoreData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Data you plan on storing is simple, then `NSUserDefaults` will work fine. If it's complex, then core data or sqlite are some alternatives.

Here is a great post on storage options: [What are the limitations of NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173625/what-are-the-limitations-of-nsuserdefaults)

[Here is another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk) that talks about things you need to do if you are working with complex data and want to store it with `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: The data that I will be saving will be just list of visited url and max of 100 urls.

Comment: @imMobile I'd use NSUserDefaults then. It's easy enough. Here is an example if you were going down the array route: http://stackoverflow.com/a/537849/59017